# How do I create/install new route_xxx.php file required by new environment

Tags: symfony, environment

For my symfony app, I need to create a new environment "qa", in addition to the existing "dev" and "prod".

I've added web/app_qa.php, including ...

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('qa', true);
```

and I've created config_qa.yml and routing_qa.yml in app/config. When I try to run ...

```
app/console server:run --env=qa
```

I get a message about not finding router_qa.php. The files for the other environments (router_dev.php and router_prod.php) are in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config. If I use

```
app/console server:run --env=qa --router=vendor/symfony/.../router_prod.php
```

(... indicates the rest of the path) then it starts up nicely.

My config_qa.yml includes a spec for routing_qa.yml, but I wasn't able to find a way to specify router_prod.php. If I copy router_prod.php to app/config, startup still complains about it being missing. I could put the copy down in the symfony vendor tree, but that seems kludgy, and I'd have to make the copy for every deployment.

Any suggestions regarding the right way to do this?

I'm running symfony 2.5.12 on ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/environments.html
have you seen the documentaion?

Comment: Yes, that cookbook page is the one I'm using. It's fine, as far as it goes, but it doesn't mention how to solve the router_xxx.php issue.
I can work around the issue by adding a route spec to "app/console server:run", but that won't work for nginx.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach is ugly, but works.

- I used the instructions in [How to Master and Create new Environments](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/environments.html) to generate web/app_qa.php and app/config/config_qa.yml, as described in the question.
- I added app/Resources/config/router_qa.php. This is a copy of vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/router_prod.php, substituting 'app_qa.php' for 'app.php'
- I modified app/Kernel, adding the following:

> ```
>     public function locateResource($name, $dir = null, $first = true)
>     {
>         if ($name == "@FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/router_qa.php")
>         {
>             return(__DIR__ . "/Resources/config/router_qa.php");
>         }
>         return(parent::locateResource($name, $dir, $first));
>     }
> ```

(There's no doubt an easy one-line approach, but I wasn't able to find it in several hours of reading symfony docs).